# Spelling Errors that Gained Legitimacy

Tags: orthography

I am trying to find examples of words that were classified as spelling errors when they first appeared, but over time gained legitimacy and are now accepted as valid words.  Is there a name for this type of word?

*(I am attempting to "spice-up" some old classroom material.)*

Comment: Democracy (or tyranny of the masses) in action.

Comment: Fuschia? Aluminium?

Comment: Eye spellings -- _hafta, hasta, hadta, sposta, wanna, shoulda, shouldna, useta, oughta, woulda, wouldna, coulda, couldna_, for instance. Most of them are modal contractions that are spelled like they're pronounced, and get only more popular as the poor doomed, inaudible apo'strophe gets completely confused and occur's as frequently in it's officially incorrect use's as in its offically correct ones. The apostrophe is in intensive care, and we know we can do without it, so many people have pulled the plug, punctuationwise.

Comment: Pretty much every single word on this page qualifies.

Comment: @JohnLawler +1 for apo'strophe. I'm gonna use that.

Comment: I think this is POB. At least *somebody* thought the "new" spelling was "correct", or they wouldn't have used it in the first place. And there was never an official universally-recognised authority on spelling in any case. But you might like to consider ***a naranja = an orange*** as a fairly clear-cut example of a spelling change.

Comment: There aren't a huge number of words whose spellimg has changed _since spelling became standardised_. But there are certainly some words I have noticed in Jane Austen with different spellings from today. _Chuse_ I think is one, but there are others which I cannot think of. I'm sure there is at least one word ending _aCe_ (C is a consonant but I forget which) where she writes _aiCe_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Was it actually ever spelled like that in English - as opposed to said like that?

Comment: @Araucaria: To be honest, I don't think of *spelling* as particularly significant in matters of language (it's only relevant to the minuscule proportion of utterances that end up getting written down). Maybe Pinker is only talking about spoken forms too, but [here's his take on it in *The Language Instinct*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UtFqXQosVP0C&pg=PT270&lpg=PT270&dq=grammar+%22a+norange%22&source=bl&ots=6G64MCCDTw&sig=idtxkCHnBuwG6doBSSPp3IPkRJk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=doI2VM-MKeaY7gb9sYCwBQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=grammar%20%22a%20norange%22&f=false)

Comment: @JohnLawler: Get outta here. Fuhgeddaboudit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google [iThinkMedia](http://www.ithinkmedia.co.uk/blog/search-engine-optimisation/evolution-google/)

> the name “Google”, which actually came from a spelling error made by
>   Larry Page when attempting to write “Googol” which meant the number 1
>   followed by one million zero’s (symbolising endless results).

cocoa [APS](http://www.apsnet.org/edcenter/K-12/NewsViews/Pages/2004_04.aspx)

> The term cocoa comes from a spelling error made during shipping of
>   cacao seeds.

aluminum [Valencia College](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=56&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDoQFjAFODI&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffd.valenciacollege.edu%2Ffile%2Frborders2%2FCHAPTER%25203%2520MATTER%2520AND%2520ENERGY.ppt&ei=Yrk1VMOkHOKu7Aaf3IDQDw&usg=AFQjCNFt7WV_k4a4LkgNL4b_0jg_RCYTaw&bvm=bv.76247554,bs.1,d.cWc)

> element #13 is called aluminum in the USA and Canada, and aluminium in
>   the rest of the world. The different spelling is believed to be from a
>   spelling error which caught on in the USA and Canada.

From an Internet chat board:  "It comes from a spelling error by a secretary that worked for Alcoa. Alcoa was dedicating a new reduction plant and the invitations were already printed so the decision was made to send them out, no time to redo them. The i was left out, aluminium to aluminum."

Jehovah [Singapore Bible College](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=90&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CF8QFjAJOFA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbiblestudydownloads.com%2FTheology_PPT%2FTheology_PPT_files%2FGriffith%2520Da%2520Vinci%2520Code%2520Notes%2520(7%2520Sep%252009%2520-19%2520pp.).doc&ei=Jrs1VMOEIamu7AbTroG4DQ&usg=AFQjCNH-CIr1LlkaSjJP2Y7Xd6uGcpsxGQ&bvm=bv.76247554,bs.1,d.cWc)

> “Jehovah” resulted from a spelling error when the vowels of the name
>   “Adonai” (Lord) were wrongly added to the sacred name of consonants
>   only: YHWH.  Thus “Yahweh” is correct.

strait-laced spelled straight-laced [AlphaDictionary](http://www.alphadictionary.com/goodword/word/strait-laced)

> has been misspelled straight-laced so many times, that most US
>   dictionaries now carry the misspelling as a legitimate alternate.

Nome, Alaska [Holland America Cruises](http://www.hollandamerica.com/assets//travelAgentHQ/2011AK_Broadside%20Map-UK-AU.pdf)

> Nome got its name from a spelling error. A British ofcer had written
>   “? Name” next to a prominent point on a chart of Alaska’s coastline.
>   When the map was recopied, the draftsman thought that the “?” was a
>   “C” and that the “a” in “Name” was an “o,” and thus a map-maker in the
>   British Admiralty christened it “Cape Nome.”

Oregon [book about Lewis and Clark](http://books.google.com/books?id=vEOgDiZlgxIC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=%22from+a+spelling+error%22&source=bl&ots=u2Dz0BcEQ9&sig=r6uOkRKgqkB3iM0eNgveM4x_rns&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M7U1VO6nO-jY7Abr7YGoAg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22from%20a%20spelling%20error%22&f=false)

> ...derives from a spelling error on a copy of a Lohotan map...

pwned [wiki](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Fun:Pwned)

> It is also believed to have come from a spelling error, since patched,
>   in the RTS game Starcraft. The message was displayed after defeating
>   another player.

*Note that since I don't trust wiki I confirmed the theory of pwned in this from* [ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/mediawatch/transcripts/0940_pwned.pdf)

dqunk according to Urban Dictionary started as a spelling error for "drunk" and has gained popularity.

esmi according to Urban Dictionary also started as a spelling error while drunk

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling) list of notable misspellings:

Notable English misspellings in history

- **Cleveland, Ohio** – the leader of the crew that surveyed the town's territory was General Moses Cleaveland, and the region was named in
  his honor; reportedly the town's first newspaper, the Cleveland
  Advertiser, could not fit the town's name in its masthead without
  removing the first "a" from the name.
- **Google** – accidental misspelling of googol. According to Google's vice president, as quoted on a BBC The Money Programme documentary,
  January 2006, the founders – noted for their poor spelling –
  registered Google as a trademark and web address before someone
  pointed out that it was not correct.
- **Ovaltine**, a popular bedtime drink in the UK and Australia, came about because someone misspelled the original name Ovomaltine on the trademark documentation.
- **Referer** – common misspelling of the word referrer. It is so common, in fact, that it made it into the official specification of HTTP – the communication protocol of the World Wide Web – and has, therefore, become the standard industry spelling when discussing HTTP referers.
- **Sequim, Washington** – "In 1879 the first post office was built and named 'Seguin' for the surrounding area. [...] In 1907, due to a Postal Official's error in reading an official report, the post office was titled 'Seguim' for approximately a month. With the next report, the Official read the letter 'g' as a 'q' and the post office here became known as 'Sequim.' The name change apparently did not worry the residents enough to protest. It has been known as Sequim ever since."
- According to some, the name of **Quartzsite**, a mining town in Arizona was spelled wrongly. It should be Quartzite, after the mineral quartzite.
- **Zenith** – Arabic zamt was misread; in Latin letters, at the time, the letter i was never dotted, so "m" looked like "ni".
- **Arab, Alabama** – This town in north Alabama was named Arad, after its founder Arad Thompson, but the name was misspelled on a US Post Office map as "Arab," and the misspelled name stuck.

also related:

the guerilla girls decision to wear gorilla masks http://femmagazine.com/?p=5760

> So what’s with the gorilla masks? According to this interview with two
>   of the original Guerrilla Girl founders, the gorilla idea came from a
>   spelling error of the word ‘guerrilla’ by one of the girls in the
>   group.

Grenada/Granada - what's the difference?  [Consumer Affairs](http://www.consumeraffairs.com/news/british-airways-mixes-up-grenada-with-granada-061014.html)

> British Airways mixes up Grenada with Granada
>
> A D.C. couple was headed for Spain but wound up in the Caribbean

Comment: Some clarifications: A [googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) is a one followed by just one hundred zeros. "[Jehovah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehovah)" is a latinization of "Yəhōwā" just as "[Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus)" comes from "Ἰησοῦς" (romanized as "Iēsoûs") via "יֵשׁוּעַ‎" (romanized as "Yēšūaʿ).